# Castle logging facade and NLog

Tags: c#, logging, nlog, castle

I'm using Castle for logging facade. I have problem when my logger is logging message. The callsite is not my Namespace.Class but is castle facade: `Castle.Services.Logging.NLogIntegration.NLogLogger.Debug`
So, how to set a callsite to be my real class that is calling this logger, and not the Castle's Nlog implementation?

Comment: @ Krzysztof Koźmic 2.5.3 Version. I was able to set logger name to my namespace.class name and to format layout to use logger name instead callsite. But still, shouldn't Castle be able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by creating logger with name of the class in which logger is and by changing configuration file to write logger name instead of call site.